# how to mix HEREDOC with backticks ``?

Tags: bash, shell

I have this script ...

```
#!/bin/sh

list=`/usr/bin/yasql user/xxxx@dev --batch` <<EOT
select h.hostname from host h, server s where s.id = h.id and s.server_type = 'DNS';
EOT

for i in $list
do
    echo $i
done
```

But of course it does not work because I don't understand how to mix the HEREDOC with backticks ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list=`/usr/bin/yasql user/xxxx@dev --batch <<EOT
select h.hostname from host h, server s where s.id = h.id and s.server_type = 'DNS';
EOT`
```